# How to access more than 4 arguments in an ARM assembly function?

Tags: assembly, arm

In my assembly function, there are 6 arguments. When I try to access the fourth and fifth arguments, they are wrong, here is my code on arm cortex-8a

```
push {r4-r8,lr}
ldr r6, [sp]
ldr r7, [sp, #4]
```

I have checked [sp] memory, r4-r8 have wrong value. But, if there are 3 or fewer arguments, [sp] gives correct r4-r8 value. Do I miss something?

Answer (score 13):

why not just try it?

```
unsigned int fun ( unsigned int, unsigned int, unsigned int, unsigned int, unsigned int );
unsigned int myfun ( void )
{
return(fun(1,2,3,4,5));
}
```

assemble then disassemble

```
> arm-none-eabi-gcc -O2 -c fun.c -o fun.o
> arm-none-eabi-objdump -D fun.o
```

assembly output contains

```
00000000 <myfun>:
   0:   e52de004    push    {lr}        ; (str lr, [sp, #-4]!)
   4:   e3a03005    mov r3, #5
   8:   e24dd00c    sub sp, sp, #12
   c:   e58d3000    str r3, [sp]
  10:   e3a01002    mov r1, #2
  14:   e3a02003    mov r2, #3
  18:   e3a03004    mov r3, #4
  1c:   e3a00001    mov r0, #1
  20:   ebfffffe    bl  0 <fun>
  24:   e28dd00c    add sp, sp, #12
  28:   e49de004    pop {lr}        ; (ldr lr, [sp], #4)
  2c:   e12fff1e    bx  lr
```

the first four operands are in registers r0-r3 as expected.  the fifth operand though is placed on the stack. why the compiler allocates 12 bytes instead of 4 for the operand, that is a mystery...Perhaps seeing the function would make more sense:

```
unsigned int fun ( unsigned int a, unsigned int b, unsigned int c, unsigned int d, unsigned int e )
{
    return(a+b+c+d-e);
}
```

assemble and disassemble

```
arm-none-eabi-gcc -O2 -c fun.c -o fun.o
arm-none-eabi-objdump -D fun.o 

00000000 <fun>:
   0:   e0811000    add r1, r1, r0
   4:   e0812002    add r2, r1, r2
   8:   e59d0000    ldr r0, [sp]
   c:   e0823003    add r3, r2, r3
  10:   e0600003    rsb r0, r0, r3
  14:   e12fff1e    bx  lr
```

so the callee simply knows the operand is the first thing on the stack and doesnt care about the stack frame created by the caller. so it is a mystery why the caller allocated 12 bytes instead of 4 in this case.

```
arm-none-eabi-gcc --version
arm-none-eabi-gcc (GCC) 4.7.2
Copyright (C) 2012 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

seeing the compiler actually implement the calling convention can make the reading of the calling convention itself more understandable.  Or if you craft examples like this for the specific function prototype you are interested in on the compiler you are interested in you dont have to read the convention, you just make your caller or callee whichever you are interested in, match what the compiler is doing for itself.

Comment: The extra 12 bytes are to keep `sp` aligned to a multiple of 16 bytes as required by the ABI.

Answer (score 11):

The extra arguments are passed on the stack, **however**, the `SP` points to them *at the entry to the function*. In your prolog you're pushing registers to be saved, and this changes the `SP`, so you need to account for it.

r4,r5,r6,r7,r8 and lr are 6 registers, so you need to adjust your `SP` offsets by 6*4 = 24 bytes. So, try the following:

```
push {r4-r8,lr}        // 6 regs are pushed
                       // SP is decremented by 6*4 = 24 bytes
ldr r6, [sp, #(0+24)]  // get first stack arg
ldr r7, [sp, #(4+24)]  // get second stack arg
```

If you do more manipulations with `SP`, e.g. allocate space for stack vars, you might have to take that into account too.

Answer (score 5):

**AAPCS standard**

http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.ihi0042f/IHI0042F_aapcs.pdf 5.5 Parameter Passing contains the answer.

It is not super easy to understand as it is an algorithm, but the crucial part that answers the question seems to be:

> C.5
>   If the NCRN is less than r4 and the NSAA is equal to the SP, the argument is split between core 
>   registers and the stack.  The first part of the argument is c
>   opied into the core registers starting at the 
>   NCRN up to and including r3.  The remainder of the argument is copied onto the stack, starting at the 
>   NSAA.  The NCRN is set to r4 and the NSAA is incremented by the size of the argument minus the 
>   amount passed 
>   in registers.  The argument has now been allocated.

Which as others said, means 4 registers + stack.